# Calculate tension and reaction forces acting on the ball hanged inside a rotating cone

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram

I can't find error in the schoolbook problem.

**Problem:** There is a cone, angle between its axis and its generator is 30 degree. Cone is rotating with velocity 1 revolutions per second. The ball is hanged on the rope that is attached to the margin of the cone. Distance between axis of cone and ball is 10 cm, ball weights 100 g. What is rope tension force and cone reaction force to ball?

I got 0,67 N and 0,84 N.  Book's answers are 0,72 N and 0,74 N. I think that there might be error in force diagram and hence in first step of my solution.

**My solution:**

[image]

1)$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
F_{sx}=-F_s sin \alpha \\
F_{sy}=F_s cos \alpha\\
F_{rx}=F_r sin \alpha\\
F_{ry}=F_r cos \alpha\\
\frac{m v^2}{R}= F_{sx}+F_{rx}\\
F_{sy}+F_{ry}-mg=0
\end{array}
\right.
$

2)$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{m v^2}{R}=-F_s sin \alpha +F_r cos \alpha\\
mg= F_s cos \alpha +F_r sin \alpha
\end{array}
\right.
$

3)${D}=\begin{vmatrix}
-sin \alpha & cos \alpha  \\ 
cos \alpha & sin \alpha \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=-sin^2 \alpha- cos^2\alpha=-1$

${D_1}=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{m v^2}{R} & cos \alpha  \\ 
m g & sin \alpha \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=\frac{m v^2}{R} sin \alpha - mg cos \alpha$

${D_2}=\begin{vmatrix}
-sin \alpha & \frac{m v^2}{R}  \\ 
cos \alpha & mg \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=- mg sin \alpha-\frac{m v^2}{R} cos \alpha$

$F_s=mg cos \alpha-\frac{m v^2}{R} sin \alpha$

$F_r=mg sin \alpha+\frac{m v^2}{R} cos \alpha$

4)Knowing that $v=2 \pi n R$

$F_s=mg cos \alpha-4 \pi^2 R n^2 m sin \alpha$

$F_r=mg sin \alpha+4 \pi^2 m R n^2 cos \alpha$

Comment: Is the,  1  rps, revolutions/sec or radians/sec?

Comment: revolutions per second

Answer (score 1):

Your sketch looks correct. I agree with your formulas. I put them into a spreadsheet and tried different inputs. With MKS units, a 30 degree angle, 1 revolution/sec, and g = 10 m/s/s, I got your answers. I found no combination of inputs that gives answers resembling the answers from your book.